# Unit testing framework for Tridion Event System

Tags: 2011, event-system

Is there any recommended testing framework for Tridion event system? MoQ testing framework can not be used as the Tridion API classes used in event system doesn't expose any interface, abstract class or class with virtual methods.

Answer (score 2):

In order to maximize the testing capabilities it is recommended to use `separation of concerns`, it is possible to use a `Dependency Injection` framework like `Ninject` then it is easy to use NUnit in Tridion Event System.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion @EricHuiza!! I went through the documentation for Ninject, it seems if I am writing total custom code then it will be very useful DI framework however in case of Tridion event system; I am dependent on Tridion API objects which I want to mock for unit testing. Moreover, those objects doesn't implement any DI framework. If you can provide any pointer for unit testing framework which can work with the classes that don't implement DI.